# How to create an imagemap using createjs

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm using CreateJS to render graphics for my game. The images are organized into Bitmaps. However I have this heart bitmap that contains both a full/half/empty hearts. How do I use the image as a imagemap?

I know there is the "mask" method, but I don't understand the reference material well enough to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best would be to use SpriteSheets:

```
var data = {
    images: ["sprites.jpg"],
    frames: {width:50, height:50},
    animations: {full:[0,0], half:[1,1], empty:[2,2]}
};
var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);
var animation = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet, "full");
```